# generate build for angular production

Tags: angularjs, bower, yo

I've built an AngularJS app. I scaffolded my app using bower and yo. Since I want to make it to production now, I'd like to know if there is a way to run a command from the cmd and generate like a distribution folder with all my dependencies in. I think I saw somebody doing that, but can't remember where. 
I ask for this, because everything is in /bower_components and in their own folders, so It would be tedious to make it manually. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You may want to look into [`Grunt`](http://gruntjs.com/) for [build automation and more](http://www.sitepoint.com/kickstart-your-angularjs-development-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/).

Comment: Here's a video I really enjoyed watching. http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/06/11/architecting-large-single-page-applications-with-knockout-js/ - its not with angularjs, but the ideas and the build process described is 100% applicable